# Missing Asset Catalog by deploying Xamarin.iOS-App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an Xamarin-App for iOS within VS for windows connected to MacinCloud. When I deploy my App as ipa-file within the Application Loader in MacinCloud, there aren't any errors. But then everytime I get an email from apple with following error:

**Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in 'MyProject.iOS.app'. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.**

Here (https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/719222/how-to-deal-with-missing-asset-catalog-response-fr.html) I found out, that **the file Assets.car is missing in my ipa-file. How can it be produced?**

My project structure:

[image: my project structure]

You see, I have all the necessary icons in it! Otherwise the application loader lead to errrors..

Also in *Info.plist* I have:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
<key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
<string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>Icon</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppStore.png</string>
            <string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-60@3x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-76.png</string>
            <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small@3x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small-20.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small-20@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small-20@3x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small-40.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small-40@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-Small-40@3x.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I'm using following versions:

- VS 15.7.4 with Xamarin.iOS 11.12.0.4
- MacinCloud with VS for Mac 7.5.3 with Xamarin.iOS 11.12.0.4 and Xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: The path *Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset* doesn't exist. It's *Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset*. I don't know why Visual Studio added this..

Comment: I am facing same issue. But after remove "Resources" from path still issue is there. Any other option?