# App Icon errors using application loader

Tags: ios, xamarin, ipa

I am trying to upload a beta of my Xamarin application and I receive the following list of errors when using the application loader:

[image]

I created my icons using [this](http://appiconmaker.co/) and the asset catalog accepted them.

[image]

Has anyone had a similar experience or have any insight into this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the information from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356091/missing-asset-catalog-by-deploying-xamarin-ios-app) I was able to successfully upload my app. To get the Assets.xcassets folder to show up in the solution explorer you can just drag the folder from file explorer into the desired location in the tree. My file names in the contents json file were also incorrect so once those were updated the icons showed up correctly.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Contractor App</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.company.contractor</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
            <string>icon</string>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon-20.png</string>
                <string>icon-29.png</string>
                <string>icon-40.png</string>
                <string>icon-58.png</string>
                <string>icon-60.png</string>
                <string>icon-76.png</string>
                <string>icon-80.png</string>
                <string>icon-87.png</string>
                <string>icon-120.png</string>
                <string>icon-152.png</string>
                <string>icon-167.png</string>
                <string>icon-180.png</string>
                <string>icon-1024.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Contractor App</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below,

1. Right click on Assets.xcassets and select Reveal in Finder.
2. Take 'Back up' your App Icons from the folder.
3. From Visual Studio, Delete current AppIcon set in the Assets.xcassets
4. Add new AppIcon set in the Assets.xcassets
5. Upload the same required icons according to your app platform type from your back up folder.
6. Select the new AppIcon set in the info.plist
7. Try Build, Archive, Sign and upload to TestFlight